# Resample time series data hourly with gaps

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a year-long data set with dates and temperatures that's sample every 15min with occasional gaps in the data in Python. I've saved the dates and temperatures into a dataframe in pandas:

```
2015-08-21 09:35:47  27.928
2015-08-21 09:55:47  28.839
2015-08-21 10:15:47  28.495
...
2016-08-10 05:39:24  11.246
2016-08-10 05:59:24  11.912
2016-08-10 06:19:24  13.066
```

I would like to resample the data into every hour and tried with this line:

```
 newDat=data.resample(rule='H')
```

I also tried using the first and last 'how' but still didn't get what I was looking for. My results looked like:

```
2015-08-21 09:00:00  28.383500
2015-08-21 10:00:00  27.959667
2015-08-21 11:00:00  29.513333
...
2016-08-10 06:00:00  14.235667
2016-08-10 07:00:00  20.867333
2016-08-10 08:00:00  26.725000
```

I don't want the actual temperature or time values changed. I would like the command to grab the first times within every hour of the day so I get something  like:

```
2015-08-21 09:15:47  27.925
2015-08-21 10:15:47  28.495
2015-08-21 11:15:47  27.596
...
2016-08-10 07:19:24  16.944
2016-08-10 08:19:24  27.149
2016-08-10 09:19:24  28.152
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DataFrame.groupby` method can accept a sequence of values as group keys.
The length of the sequence is expected to be the same as the number of rows in the DataFrame, and rows corresponding to equal-valued items in the sequence are grouped.

So you could use dates truncated to the nearest hour as group keys:

```
In [133]: groupkey = data['date'].values.astype('datetime64[h]'); groupkey
Out[133]: 
array(['2015-08-21T09', '2015-08-21T09', '2015-08-21T10', '2016-08-10T05',
       '2016-08-10T05', '2016-08-10T06'], dtype='datetime64[h]')
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
Timestamp = pd.Timestamp
data = pd.DataFrame({'date': [Timestamp('2015-08-21 09:35:47'), Timestamp('2015-08-21 09:55:47'), Timestamp('2015-08-21 10:15:47'), Timestamp('2016-08-10 05:39:24'), Timestamp('2016-08-10 05:59:24'), Timestamp('2016-08-10 06:19:24')], 'temp': [27.928000000000001, 28.839000000000002, 28.495000000000001, 11.245999999999999, 11.912000000000001, 13.065999999999999]}) 

groupkey = data['date'].values.astype('datetime64[h]')
result = data.groupby(groupkey).first().set_index('date')
print(result)
```

yields

```
                       temp
date                       
2015-08-21 09:35:47  27.928
2015-08-21 10:15:47  28.495
2016-08-10 05:39:24  11.246
2016-08-10 06:19:24  13.066
```

Comment: I get 'ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy datetime' when I try the groupkey line.

Comment: What version of Numpy and Pandas are you using? (Check `np.__version__` and `pd.__version__`). Also, what is `data['date'].values.dtype`?

Comment: numpy version '1.10.4' and pandas version '0.17.1', and dtype('O')

Comment: `dtype('O')` suggests that `data['date']` might be strings (or worse, a mixture of strings, Timestamps and perhaps other stuff...). To use the code above, `data['date']` should be a Series of dtype `datetime64[ns]`. To *try* convert it to that dtype, use `data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])`. If that succeeds, then `groupkey = data['date'].values.astype('datetime64[h]')` will work.